# Retornar Id's Que Não Estão no Banco de Dados - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, query

**Problema**

Em uma tabela *X* e possuo *N* registros, porém esses registros não são sequenciais(em todo *insert*, Id será sempre maior que o anterior, mas não necessariamente o número seguinte ao anterior).

Preciso saber quais são os id's que não possuo no banco.

**Exemplo**

```
SELECT Id FROM X
```

Retornaria

```
Id
1
2
4
8
12
```

Preciso retornar os Id's `3,5,6,7,9,10,11` que estão faltando.

Procurei bastante, mas só encontrei resultados em inglês e esses resultados infelizmente não solucionaram o problema.

**Questão**

Como criar uma query capaz de resolver isso em apenas **uma coluna** e sem a criação de outras tabelas ?

Answer (score 1):

Tenta essa solução: joguei todos os *ID* que existem em uma tabela temporária com o *status* de "existe"; depois, com um contador, checa quem não existe e adiciona com o *status* de "nao existe".

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmpIds;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmpIds SELECT Id, 'existe' as 'Status' FROM X

DECLARE maior_id INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE contador INT DEFAULT 1;
DECLARE existe varchar(3);

SELECT maior_id = MAX(Id) FROM X

WHILE contador <= maior_id DO
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tmpIds WHERE Id = contador)
        INSERT INTO tmpIds(Id, Status) VALUES(contador, 'nao existe');

    SET contador = contador +1;
END WHILE;

SELECT * FROM tmpIds
```

Comment: Fui informado que não posso criar tabelas, devido ao ORM.

Comment: não pode fazer isso via código? carregar os que existem na base e ver o que não foi retornado?

Comment: A intenção de fazer via query, era evitar um desenvolvimento de uma aplicação que seria desnecessária.

Answer (score 1):

Tenta usar esta query, se quiseres ler mais aqui tens [**link**](http://www.codediesel.com/mysql/sequence-gaps-in-mysql/)

```
SELECT a.id + 1 AS start, MIN(b.id) - 1 AS end
    FROM minha_tabela AS a, minha_tabela  AS b
    WHERE a.id < b.id
    GROUP BY a.id
    HAVING start < MIN(b.id)
```

E Vai te retornar os registos em falta na ordem sequencial

**Nota** id é tudo minúsculo, ve se o teu id também é tudo minúsculo

Comment: Ele está retornando o resultado em duas colunas, vou precisar analisar caso a caso manualmente para obter os faltantes, preciso retornar a sequencia completa faltante.

Comment: Alteraste o codigo corretamente ?

Comment: Sim, ele gera coluna "start" e a coluna "end", precisaria só de uma coluna.

Answer (score 0):

Segue abaixo uma solução em uma query:

```
SELECT
    y.id
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            @row := @row + 1 as id
        FROM 
            (select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t,
            (select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t2, 
            (select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t3, 
            (select 0 union all select 1 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) t4, 
            (SELECT @row:=0) AS y
    ) AS y
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT 1 AS id UNION SELECT 2 AS id UNION SELECT 4 AS id UNION SELECT 5 AS id UNION SELECT 12 AS id) AS x ON y.id = x.id
WHERE
    x.id IS NULL
    AND y.id < (SELECT MAX(id) FROM (SELECT 1 AS id UNION SELECT 2 AS id UNION SELECT 4 AS id UNION SELECT 5 AS id UNION SELECT 12 AS id) AS x)
```

Só precisaria substituir os treços (SELECT 1 AS id UNION SELECT 2 AS id UNION SELECT 4 AS id UNION SELECT 5 AS id UNION SELECT 12 AS id) pela sua tabela do banco. E esta solução teria uma limitação de até 10.000 registros.